# CakePHP: Save Model loaded from MySQL View

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a CakePHP-Model "Person", which loads its data from a mysql-view (`public $useTable = 'people_rel';`, people_rel is the view).
The view connects some data to the table 'people'.

**The view prefix_people_rel:**

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `xxxxxxx`@`%` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `prefix_people_rel` AS
    select 
        `prefix_people`.`id` AS `id`,
        `prefix_people`.`username` AS `username`,
        `prefix_people`.`first_name` AS `first_name`,
        `prefix_people`.`last_name` AS `last_name`,
        `prefix_people`.`email` AS `email`,
        `prefix_people`.`password` AS `password`,
        `prefix_people`.`status` AS `status`,
        `prefix_people`.`outpost_id` AS `outpost_id`,
        `prefix_outposts`.`region_id` AS `region_id`,
        `prefix_regions`.`district_id` AS `district_id`,
        `prefix_districts`.`country_id` AS `country_id`
    from
        (((`prefix_people`
        left join `prefix_outposts` ON ((`prefix_people`.`outpost_id` = `prefix_outposts`.`id`)))
        left join `prefix_regions` ON ((`prefix_outposts`.`region_id` = `prefix_regions`.`id`)))
        left join `prefix_districts` ON ((`prefix_regions`.`district_id` = `prefix_districts`.`id`)))
```

**The table prefix_people:**
[image: The table prefix_people]

The columns region_id, district_id and country_id are read-only in this model, they are edited in the models Outpost, Region and District.
The problem is that i can't save the model, because it's loaded from view.
I'd like to load the data from the view people_rel and save them into the table people. How can i do this? (I use CakePHP 2.5.3 and want to upgrade to 3 once the stable version is avaiable)

Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
This has not helped:
**Model Person:**

```
public function beforeSave($options = array())
{
    // ... Password hashing ...
    $this->useTable = 'people';
    return true;
}

public function afterSave($created, $options = array()) {
    $this->useTable = 'people_rel';
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
A really similar solution works. See the answer below.

Comment: it's not clear if you are using the same model `People` to read and save. But if it is, have you tried changing the table alias (and database table) at the beginning of `beforeSave` and changing it back to `people_rel` at the end of afterSave? Am I misunderstanding your problem?

Comment: I'm reading the data from the view 'people_rel' and want to write the changes to the table 'people', But it is all done from the Model 'Person'. I tried your idea with before- and afterSave (see my edit), but it didn't work.

Comment: Based on your idea, i found a solution. I'll add it below. Thanks!

Comment: That's great! Will keep this in mind if I have to do something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the idea from Nunser i found a solution.
In the model, i added *beforeSave()* and afterSave():

```
public function beforeSave($options = array())
{
    //$this->useTable = 'people'; <= Does not work
    $this->setSource('people'); // Works
    return true;
}

public function afterSave($created, $options = array()) {
    //$this->useTable = 'people_rel'; <= Does not work
    $this->setSource('people_rel'); // Works
}
```

**Necessary for deleting objects:**

```
public function beforeDelete($cascade = true) {
    $this->setSource('people');
    return true;
}

public function afterDelete() {
    $this->setSource('people_rel');
}
```